# How to preserve the ModelMap between form submits?

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc

I am adding to the `ModelMap` a `Map` which contains a list to go on a drop down an I am populating the ModelAttribute when the form initialises:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initForm(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, ModelMap model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("myList", myMap);
        return "MyForm";
    }
```

It works as expected however when the user submits the form this list is lost from the map.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value ="/dosearch")
    public String processSearch(... ModelMap model)
    {
                .....
    return new ModelAndView("MyForm",model);
```

This approach above doesn't work.

How can I prserve the map between form submits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Even a flash scope won't help you here, because you are not using redirect-after-post. Here are the options:

- output all values in the html form, then they will be submitted to `/dosearch` and you'll be able to get them from the request
- use the session to store the values (worse option)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please show me a code example of the first option? What about spring:bind?

Comment: Also I am happy to consider redirect after post. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: it serves a different purpose

Comment: So I'm supposed to dump all the values to the html in dynamic hidden fields? sounds a bit messy to me. Any concrete code example to support that?

Comment: yes, that's what you should do. It's messy, but http is stateless protocol - you can't keep things persistent across requests, unless you use the session