# How to preserve data between two calls to controller methods?

Tags: java, jsp

I have 2 JSPs: `pay.jsp`, `confirmPay.jsp`

User submits data (credit card# etc.) on `pay.jsp`. This data is validated at the backend and is displayed along with some other data, on `confirmPay.jsp`. Once he clicks on 'Confirm', the data (from the `pay.jsp` page) is used for billing. If he clicks 'Cancel', the payment is discarded.

The important things here are:

1. Data should be modifiable only in `pay.jsp`
2. Data should be preserved between the two calls

I know this question is similar to [How to preserve the ModelMap between form submits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019132/how-to-prserve-the-modelmap-between-form-submits). Just wanted to know what works for situations like this, that involves sensitive information (like credit card#). Putting it in a session would mean that multiple calls in the same function will create issues.

Please help me understand what the best choice is.

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided in the answer? Check this line from Bozho: *you can't keep things persistent across requests, unless you use the session*. Have you tried anything knowing this? Also, what kind of *problems* you will have if you put the object in the user session?

Comment: That should work, but as I've pointed out at the bottom of the question, it would mean that only one transaction can be done at a time. Another thing to do would be to store a random "id" together with the session attribute and distinguish the data based on that id. I just wanted to know what the best way is

Comment: Suppose that you have this info in a `PaymentInfo` class. Then, you just had to save it: `session.setAttribute("paymentInfo", oPaymentInfo);` and retrieve it when you need it: `PaymentInfo oPaymentInfo = (PaymentInfo)session.getAttribute("paymentInfo");`. After the transaction is done (either by the `Confirm` or `Cancel` user action), you should remove this data from the session: `session.removeAttribute("paymentInfo");`, as simple as that. If you need to hold more data in session, you can store a `Set<PaymentInfo>` instead and override the `hashCode` and `equals` method in the `PaymentInfo`.

Comment: Remove the data from the session after you complete the transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned about storing sensitive data in the session, then don't worry. The session is held in memory at server-side. It doesn't goes on the wire, and can't be read from the browser memory of by an intruder on the network.

If you're concerned about users having multiple opened browser tabs or frames on the same pages, and sending several payments in parallel, in the same session, then it's a very valid concern. I tend to prefer stateless solutions, so if hidden fields are an acceptable solution, then just use them to maintain state from one page to the next one. This won't cause any problem with multiple tabs. If you need to use the session to store intermediate state, then you can simply generate a unique ID (using a sequence number, for example), store the data in the session using the unique ID as session attribute, and pass this unique ID frompage to page using a hidden field. That way, multiple tabs will use different session attributes, and won't disturb each other.

Comment: Or,as I've stated in my comment, you can save the payment data in a `Set` and this set will be stored in the session. Still, your explanation is really good.

Comment: You still need a way to associate a given request, coming from a given browser tab, to a given payment. How would you do that with just a set of payments in the session?